# Servir página html haciendo login previamente y usando Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, login, backend, frontend

Quiero servir un fichero html con un fichero js asociado tras hacer login.

Hasta ahora he probado lo siguiente:
Tengo el siguiente fichero desde el que arranco el servidor:

```
//Librerias
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
//Librerías 'nuestras'//////////////////////////////////////
const mongoUtil = require("./bbdd/mongoDBUtil");

const interceptorJWT = require("./autenticacion/interceptorJWT").interceptorJWT;

//Routers para express
const usuariosRouter = require("./rest/usuariosREST").router;
const autenticacionRouter =
  require("./autenticacion/autenticacionRouter").router;
const cors = require("cors");
whitelist = ["http://localhost:5500", "http://localhost:5501"];
//Primer paso: leer el fichero de configuracion
require("./util/configUtil");

//Segundo paso: conectar a la bbdd
//aqui cojo la promesa que se ha programado en mongoUtil
mongoUtil
  .conectarBBDD()
  //aqui me traigo el then y el catch del archivo, lo paso aqui
  .then(function () {
    //esto es el resolve que mando desde desde mongoUtil
    //Tercer paso: arrancar el servidor
    arrancarServidor();
    //lo que sale de aqui es lo q entra en la funcion de la promesa del resolve del archivo MongoDBUtil
  })
  .catch(function () {
    process.exit(2);
    //lo que sale de aqui es lo que entra en reject del archivo MongoDBUtil
  });

function arrancarServidor() {
  console.log("Arrancando el servidor...");

  let app = express();

  //Interceptores (en express los llaman middleware)
  app.use(
    express.json({
      limit: "5mb", //Tamaño máximo del body que estamos dispuestos a leer. IMPRESCINDIBLE
    })
  );
  app.use(cors({ origin: whitelist, credentials: true,optionSuccessStatus:200 }));
  app.use(interceptorLog);
  app.use(interceptorCORS);
  app.use(interceptorJWT);

  //Routers
  app.use(autenticacionRouter);
  app.use(usuariosRouter);

  //Arrancamos el puerto
  http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.app_puerto, function () {
    console.log("Esperando peticiones en el puerto " + process.env.app_puerto);
  });

  //Mandamos el frontend al puerto 3000
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../frontend/'));

app.listen('3000', function() {
  console.log('Servidor escuchando en el puerto 3000');
});

}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//MIDDLEWARE. Funciones interceptoras///////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function interceptorLog(request, response, next) {
  console.log("==============================================");
  console.log("Peticion recibida: " + request.method + " " + request.url);
  next();
}

function interceptorCORS(request, response, next) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------------");
  console.log("Interceptor CORS");
  //Cross Origin Resource Sharing
  //Vamos a añadir estos headers a todas las respuestas que demos, sean options o no:
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
  );
  response.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );

  if (request.method.toUpperCase() == "OPTIONS") {
    response.end();
    return;
  }

  next();
}
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas en local. Se observa que hay dos partes una es para procesar las peticiones a la base de datos que usa el puerto 5500 y otra parte que sirve la web estática escuchando desde el puerto 3000.

La verdad es que cuando hago desde el navegador: "localhost:3000" Me sale un mensaje que dice:
"Falta la cabecera de autorización", creo que viene del siguiente fichero (interceptorJWT):

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const JWTUtil = require("../util/JWTUtil");

//El token vendrá en el header 'authorization'
//Authorization: Bearer hfjkshgjrwhfjwrhf4jf.jkhfjkeqhduiyrui2fgh42.mndehwuig43yrt428
exports.interceptorJWT = function (request, response, next) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------------");
  console.log("Interceptor JWT");

  // :(
  let urlSinParametros = request.url.split("?")[0];
  if (
    (request.method.toUpperCase() == "POST" && urlSinParametros == "/login") ||
    (request.method.toUpperCase() == "POST" && urlSinParametros == "/usuarios")
  ) {
    next();
    return; //pa no seguir
  }

  //Leemos el header 'authorization'
  let authorization = request.headers.authorization;

  if (!authorization) {
    response
      .status(401)
      .json({ codigo: 401, mensaje: "Falta la cabecera de autorización" });
    return;
  }

  let trozos = authorization.split(" ");
  if (trozos.length != 2 || trozos[0].toLowerCase() != "bearer") {
    response.status(400).json({
      codigo: 401,
      mensaje: "La cabecera authorization está mal construida",
    });
    return;
  }

  let token = trozos[1];

  try {
    let payload = jwt.verify(token, JWTUtil.getClave()); //, {algorithm: 'HS512'})
    request.autoridad = payload;
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(401).json({ codigo: 401, mensaje: err.message });
    return;
  }

  next();
};
```

Comment: El código es tuyo o estás trabajando sobre un código existente? En cuanto al mensaje, es claro que te falta implementar lógica en el lado cliente para manejar el login y obtener el token de autorización.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, el código no es mío.  He tomado un código que era para hacer login y poder hacer peticiones a una base de datos mediante un token y he tomado otro código que simplemente servía una web estática y los he metido en un mismo fichero main.js

Comment: @MauricioContreras, supongamos que hago una página para hacer login y consigo obtener el token de autorización. ¿Cómo lo mandaría al servidor? ¿Mediante una petición GET? ¿Y en el lado del servidor como lo recibiría y enviaría la página?

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, existen muchas formas de hacer lo que pides. Por el código que tienes, deberías usar una cabcera http para enviar el token desde el cliente al servidor. Aquí resolvemos problemas concretos, te sugiero que busques información sobre cómo implementar autenticación mediante JWT. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, pienso que podría contestarme alguien con la solución más sencilla posible (de entre todas esas soluciones) o si no con al menos una solución. Yo he puesto lo que he intentado hacer pero alguien que quiera contestarme no tiene porque valerse del código que he puesto.

Comment: Pasa que el código no es solo para las soluciones. Son también una demostración de que eres parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda. No siempre se necesita código, pero muchas veces es necesario. En realidad en realidad, lo que esperamos generalmente es un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).